# As a iPhone developer is it necessary to learn Apple script?

Tags: iphone, scripting

I am developing application for iPhone environment for 1 year from now,In a recent interview one of my interviewer asked me regarding Apple scripting.

So i want to know as a iPhone developer is it necessary to learn Apple script?

What are the benifit of its uses? Where can i learn it?

Comment: My personal experience indicates a `no`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because you won't be using it on the iPhone. It's not supported and you can use Cocoa Touch, UIKit and Objective-C to create your Apps on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge of AppleScript is not presently needed.

AppleScript would be useful for automating the activity of multiple applications.

There is no way to easily control one application from another, except by way of URLs.

Also, on the iPhone, each app resides its own sandbox. The iPhone's iOS 4 restricts the activities of multiple applications to prevent excess battery usage.

It is unlikely but might be possible, one day, for AppleScript to be used to control multiple applications. At this time, knowledge of it is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have never used AppleScript related to iPhone programming.

I'd say it is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (and can't use) applescript on the iPhone, as others have said.
If you need to know about it for other purposes such as this job interview, information on it is on apples site here: [Applescript](http://developer.apple.com/applescript/)